# How do I add a DbContext to an MSTest project?

Tags: c#, mstest, dbcontext

I trying to test some code that uses Entity Framework, but I can't figure out how to reference the EF Context classes from the separate MSTest project. Both projects are in the same solution.

> Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'DbContextOptions' because it is not a delegate type

In my Test case:

```
[TestClass]
public class GreenCardUserTest
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestAddUser()
    {
        // REFERENCE TO OTHER PROJECT. WORKS FINE
        AppUserViewModel a = new AppUserViewModel();

        //LIKELY INCORRECT attempt to duplicate code from Startup.cs in other project
        using (GreenCardContext _gc = new GreenCardContext(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyConnection"))))
        {
            new GCLandingUserModel().AddUser(a,_gc);
        }
    }
}
```

Excerpt from main project Startup.cs (which works fine):

```
services.AddDbContext<GreenCardContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyConnection")));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest using `InMemoryDatabase`. In your test class, use `[TestInitialize]` to setup your dummy database:

```
[TestClass]
public class GreenCardUserTest
{
    private readonly context;

    [TestInitialize]
    public Setup()
    {
        DbContextOptions<GreenCardContext> options;
        var builder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<GreenCardContext>();
        builder.UseInMemoryDatabase();
        var options = builder.Options;
        context = new GreenCardContext(options);
    }
    
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestAddUser()
    {
        // user context here...
    }
}
```

Comment: Using the In-Memory

Answer (score 1):

The code that you have from `Startup.cs` is using a delegate to tell your application how to build your DbContext at runtime.

However in your test, you need to actually provide an instance of `DbContextOptions`, not just a delegate. To do this, you can use `DbContextOptionsBuilder`:

```
var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<GreenCardContext>() 
.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyConnection"))
.Options;

using (GreenCardContext _gc = new GreenCardContext(options)) 
{ 
    new GCLandingUserModel().AddUser(a,_gc);
}
```

Also, if you do insist on unit testing your DbConext, you may want to look into using  InMemoryDatabase so that you don't need an open SQL connection in your tests. See [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/testing/in-memory#writing-tests) for more details.

Comment: I keep getting: `\'Configuration' does not contain a definition for 'GetConnectionString'`

Comment: I had just copied that section from the code you had originally posted. Maybe you meant to use `ConfigurationManager` instead of `Configuration`?

Comment: thanks, I ended up passing a hardcoded conn string because my test project couldnt access my real projects appsettings.json

Answer (score 1):

What you have to do is:

1) Add a reference in your test project to your context's project (if you haven't already)

2) Add references to Entity Framework to your test project

3) Add an appconfig to your test project and set entity framework config on it. Your test will read the configuration from it's own config, not your app's. Very useful as you can, by example, use dblocal and codefirst in tests and sqlserver when on running :)

You have done some of this, I think the point you are missing is the third :)